# Python- How to find missed dictionary item by comparing two dictionary list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the missed dictionary element by comparing two dictionary list

```
list1=[{"amount":"1000",'dept':'marketing',"desig":"mgr",'id':'101'},
{"amount":"1331",'dept':None,"desig":"accnt",'id':'102'},{"amount":"1351",'dept':'mark',"desig":"sales",'id':'103'}]


list2=[{"amount":"1500",'dept':None,"desig":"mgr2",'id':'101'},
{"amount":"1451",'dept':'IT',"desig":"accnt",'id':'102'}]

difference=[item for item in list1 if item["id"] not in list2]
```

but its not giving the expected output for the missed key

expected output:

```
missed={"amount":"1351",'dept':'mark',"desig":"sales",'id':'103'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edited question requires matching against the `'id'` key, not the entire dictionary object as before. Since that is hashable, it is simplest to put it in a `set` to efficiently test whether something is part of the collection or not. (Edit: Credit @KellyBundy for suggesting set comprehension)

```py
id_set = {item['id'] for item in list2}
difference = [item for item in list1 if item['id'] not in id_set]
```

`difference` here gives a `list` of all missing dictionaries. So to access all of them, you need to iterate over it.

```py
for missed in difference:
    print(f'{missed=}')
```

and the output will be (it will print one line per dictionary)

```
missed={'amount': '1351', 'dept': 'mark', 'desig': 'sales', 'id': '103'}
```

If you know there will only be one missing item, or you only need the first element, you can use `difference[0]` to directly access the dictionary.

Comment: i tried with another example of different key values and to filter only the missed key from the second list, but that's not giving the expected one..

Comment: Your edited input/output is a completely different operation from your original question. Instead of comparing entire dictionary items, you want to perform a match based on certain keys and ignore other keys. You're going to need to be clear about how you want to determine "missed" vs not missed. Is it just the `id` key or do you consider more? Also, you keep writing `missed={...}`, what do you expect when there are multiple missing dicts, do you want a list or not?

Comment: i need list of missed keys..

Comment: Better use a set comprehension instead of calling `set` on a generator iterator.